# iOS says BLE Characteristic is not notifying

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I am using an Adafruit Feather BLE module to tinker with.

Along with it comes the AT Command set which I am using to create a custom Service and a Characteristic with it. I am using it the notify option. The iOS side code says the Characteristic is not notifying. I did some googling and some people said a descriptor is needed for a Characteristic to be notifying. So I added one, but still no success.

Here is the Adafruit side of the code --

```
AT+GATTADDSERVICE=UUID128= 3d-e8-3e-34-dc-98-43-d0-87-de-3d-97-73-8b-ba-b6
AT+GATTADDCHAR=UUID=0xABCD, PROPERTIES=0x10, MIN_LEN=2, VALUE='01', DATATYPE=1, DESCRIPTION=TEST, PRESENTATION=17-00-AC-27-01-00-00
```

I see in the Serial Monitor that its successful. After this I am writing to the BLE module every few milliseconds.

On the iOS side, here is the log I get --

```
Characteristics: [<CBCharacteristic: 0x2817a4180, UUID = ABCD, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>]
```

I am using standard code that comes with the examples.
Is the property value I am using not the correct one? The Adafruit documentation says 0x10 is to make it notifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*notifying = no* in the debug description indicates that you have not enabled notifications for this characteristic (i.e. its `isNotifying` property is `false`).  It doesn't mean that the characteristic doesn't support notifications.

You need to call [`setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue) to enable notifications.

You will then get a call to the [`didUpdateNotificationState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518768-peripheral) delegate callback to tell you whether notifications were successfully enabled or not.

Comment: I thought when I create the characteristic for my service I need to specify whether it would notify or not. Isn't it? That "notifying = no" is the property of the characteristic as read from the module after the first connection.  I do call setNotify on it but the didUpdateNotfucationState never gets called. May be I am not understanding this properly. I want to send data using that Characteristic every 100 ms. I need the notification and the didUpdateNotificationState to be called for that right?

Comment: You do, and you have. That is what the properties = 0x10 indicates. Notifying = no means that you haven't successfully enabled notification on the iOS side. Have you set the peripheral's delegate in order to get the didUpdateNotification state callback? You need to show more of your iOS code

Comment: Ah thanks! Actually I don't know what I did. I reloaded the Arduino and the iOS app and now it works. Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately I haven't checked it into git to see what changes I made inadvertently.